# Unable to import JS module. Recieving SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

I am trying to export a function checkCashRegister() from a file src/module.js and import it to a different file src/main.js. I am currently getting 'SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module'.

```
<script src="src/main.js" defer type="module"></script>
<script src="src/module.js" type="module"></script>
```

```
const checkCashRegister = (price, cash, cid) => {...};
export default checkCashRegister;
```

```
import checkCashRegister from "./module";
```

My import statement is at the top of my src/main.js file. I'm using node v16.17.0. I have also already tried using require instead of import, not using default, and using module.exports. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using any type of code bundler/build? Is there a package.json in there? I was able to get this working just based on the code you posted, but I don't know if you have some other files that are affecting it in your folder. Check out this example: https://gist.github.com/kauffmanes/dcc3609a680da317f781d67b2d6c36d7

Comment: As far as I know there isnt a bundler/build or a package.json. I would have to assume that my issue is from code that I did not include in my example, considering you were able to get it to work. but that does surprise me, becasue I dont think any of my other code should affect the import.

Comment: Do you have a repo or more code you can post? I can take a look. Or maybe just try going through each of your imports and commenting them out and see if there's one causing it.